# Error al iniciar Activity

Tags: android-studio

No puedo cambiar de activity, tengo un usuario y password fijo para cambiar pero, la validación no me lo permite

```
etUser = findViewById(R.id.etUser);

etPassw = findViewById(R.id.etPassw); 
    

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {

// al validar el usuario y contraseña fijo, no me permite cambiar de activity, no realiza ninguna
//linea de código, necesito que al validar el usuario y contraseña fijos me cambien de activity


            if (etUser.getText().equals("Carlos") && etPassw.getText().equals("12345")) {  

                Intent intento = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityPrincipal.class);  
                intento.putExtra("usuario",etUser.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intento);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos Correctos",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos ncorrectos",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
```

### He visto e intentado con diferentes sentencias pero no me han funcionado, al parecer puede ser algo
sencillo, pero apenas estoy iniciando con android, no tengo mucho conocimiento

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre? ¿Se muestra el `Toast` de datos incorrectos? ¿No se muestra nada?

Comment: Hola @Ricardo Ortega Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Te invito a que hagas el [Recorrido por el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y ganes tu primera medalla. También es muy importante que revises las recomendaciones de [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Al ingresar los mismos valores en usuario y password, no me permite cambiar de activity, solo me manda el msj de Toast Datos incorrectos

Comment: @RicardoOrtega se muestra algún error en el LogCat? es importante definir esto ya que puede ser el problema en otra parte.}